# Enabling PODIO debugging to file podio-php

Tags: php, debugging, podio

Can anyone assist me in enabling PODIO debugging to file?

I have tried
`Podio::set_debug(true, '/opt/bitnami/apps/Scraper/PodioDebug.txt');`
but no file is ever created. also tried
   `Podio::set_debug(true);`

and no file is created in /vendor/podio/podio-php

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

The answer was right in front of me. In order to have podio log to a file use the following command.

```
Podio::set_debug(true,'file');
```

This will log to the file located in `/podio-php/log/podio.log`. In order to log to a different file, you will need to modify the `/podio-php/lib/PodioLogger.php`